# Percent of total from subgroups - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI and got stuck with the following problem:

For research purposes, I have some data about the participation of students of acourse (the example chart you can see is filtered by students not visiting the course.

The first barchart shows how many students visited those course, the second chart should show those values in percent, calculated from the subtotal.

So the value in percent of Bachelor in SS 15 should be 23,305% (total bachelor students in SS15 was 2533: 595 / 2533 * 100)

I am not able to get this values correctly calculated.

[image]

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
The Data is structured as followed:

```
Hash   Semester   Status   Stg   (...)
xxx1    SS 15       A     Diplom
xxx2    WS 16/17    A     Master
xxx1    SS 15       N     Diplom
xxx1    SS 17       A     Bachelor
xxx2    SS 15       N     Bachelor
...      ...       ...     ...
```

The hash is the identifier for the Student.
The data contains around 55.000 rows and is imported as an unstructured Excel-list. The chart is filtered by status.

Until now I dont use custom measures but the build in measures via drag and drop.
I got the percentage values by selecting "show value as percent from column total".

Comment: Provide sample data and measures you are using for those presentations.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create these following 3 measures-

**1.**

```
hash_total = COUNT(your_table_name[Hash])
```

**2.**

```
hash_semester_total = 

var cur_sem = MAX(your_table_name[Semester])

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(your_table_name[Hash]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Semester] = cur_sem
    )
)
```

**3.**

```
hash_percentage = [hash_total]/[hash_semester_total]
```

Change the Type of measure "hash_percentage" as **%**

Now configure your **clustered column chart** as below-

[image]

The output will be as below-

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I tried your solution, but couldn't get the values I was looking for. The measure hash_semester_total returns the total sum of students for each semester. What I need is the total sum for each 
degree course (Stg) for each semester.

I'd be pleased, if you also coul helpo me with that.

Comment: stg is placed in the Legend section of chart. Rest should work automatically as you see my output.

Comment: In measure 1, I have counted Hash as "hash_total = COUNT(bar_chart_data[Stg])". You can also do the count on stg in that Measure. Both case the output will be same.

Comment: Your're right, the way I thought about the values didnt't make sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are most welcome @frankvanlampe. Nice to see that it helped.